# Patch installation SUPEE-10570

Tags: magento-1, patches, magento1.9.2.4

In the website, all patch installed manually without ssh,

Can we skip SUPEE-10497 patch and install directly SUPEE-10570 because we have already installed SUPEE-10415, SUPEE-10266

Website magento version is 1.9.2.4

Refer screenshot:- https://prnt.sc/j6as6l

Thanks,

Comment: Yes you can. But take backup before you apply patch for safety.

Comment: I have done R&D we dont need to apply SUPEE-10497 if magento version 1.9.2.4, This patch SUPEE-10497 only for 1.9.1.1